# How to get Ethereum transaction list by address in java web3j quickly?

Tags: solidity, web3j, java

**Im trying to fetch transaction logs from ganache using web3j library to send it as an api ,is there any way where i can get all transactions from ganache quickly?**

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public List<Transaction> test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    String address = "0xeedc155ae507fb0a9becae6315286183a23229b0";
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    Web3j web3j = web3jConfig.initializeWeb3j();
    System.out.println("test Running.......");
    BigInteger block = web3j.ethBlockNumber().send().getBlockNumber();
    System.out.println("blockno:" + block.intValue());
    int block_no = block.intValue();



Flowable<Transaction> replyBlocks   = web3j.replayPastTransactionsFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST);
replyBlocks.forEach(temp->{
    System.out.println("into replyBlocks");
    System.out.println(temp.getBlockNumber());
        transactions.add(temp); //It's an collection object,and value is not adding into it 
})  ;

    return transactions;
}
```

**web3j.replayPastTransactionsFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST); *this function is working fine when print data to console but don't know why its not adding its data into an List object which i want to send as an api**

Comment: What is 0xeedc155ae507fb0a9becae6315286183a23229b0"?

Comment: Its an contract address @MajdTL , i just copy pasted this code from github to what it does !

Comment: So you want to extract all transactions *logs* (not transactions) that sent to a specific smart contract ?

Comment: @MajdTL yes i need all transaction logs but not from a specific contract as erc20 already provided inbuilt flowable function to achieve contract based blocks informations,I'm actully looking for a way where i can fetch all transactionLogs of ether through web3j class,currenlt using test network and ganache

Comment: you are doing it already in "replayTransactionsFlowable" ?! what is the problem?

Comment: @MajdTL wheni call that function through an api,it takes more time to fetch data which results in failure

Comment: better to use "replayTransactionsFlowable( <startBlockNumber>,  <endBlockNumber>)". There is no other way, you should iterate all blocks from 0 to the current block. maybe you can do it in parallel 
e.g. from blocks 0 to 100 in one thread, from 100 to 200 in other thread....
anyway this will not work on the main net

Comment: @MajdTL thank you ,will research more on this,anyways how about connecting over Linkdin or any other platforms?

Comment: @MajdTL " Flowable<Transaction> replyBlocks = web3j.replayPastTransactionsFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST);
" this snippet of code is working fine but im not able to add this object into an collection object of same type

Comment: why replay*Past*TransactionsFlowable and not replayTransactionsFlowable?

Comment: can you add your imported java classes above in code, cause you need 
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Transaction . do you have it?

Comment: @MajdTL I've added 'org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.' in my imports and 'replayTransactionsFlowable' is now deprecated as its not present in library

Comment: Still not working? Upload your code somewhere so I can easily test it

Comment: or better to open a new clean question

Comment: @MajdTL here's an link to another QS https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79857/not-able-to-add-replaypasttransactionsflowable-transaction-logs-result-into-an