# Not able to add 'replayPastTransactionsFlowable' transaction logs result into an collection List object using Web3j java?

Tags: web3j, java

**I'm trying to create an api where i have to provide transaction logs in json objects but im unable to add result of replayPastTransactionsFlowable 
 into an collection object**

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
public List<Transaction> test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    String address = "0xeedc155ae507fb0a9becae6315286183a23229b0";
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    Web3j web3j = web3jConfig.initializeWeb3j();
    System.out.println("test Running.......");
    BigInteger block = web3j.ethBlockNumber().send().getBlockNumber();
    System.out.println("blockno:" + block.intValue());
    int block_no = block.intValue();


Flowable<Transaction> replyBlocks   = web3j.replayPastTransactionsFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST);
replyBlocks.forEach(temp->{
    System.out.println("into replyBlocks");
    System.out.println(temp.getBlockNumber());
        transactions.add(temp); //It's an collection object,and value is not adding into it 
})  ;

    return transactions;
}
```

}
Im using following two dep

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>contracts</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: which version of web3j are you using

Comment: @MajdTL just updated the QS with web3j version

Comment: you get an error by transaction.add(temp) or it just return an empty array?

Comment: if you got an empty array, it mean your code responds back before adding the transactions to the list. i will check if you can somehow wait unitl it finish

Comment: @MajdTL yes,im getting an empty array and not getting any error at transaction.add(temp)

Comment: you should wait before "return transactions" im looking for a good way to do it

Comment: Yes I'm also trying @MajdTL

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.DefaultBlockParameterName;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Transaction;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.Web3ClientVersion;
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SimpleResource {

    @GetMapping("/transactions")
    public Flowable<Transaction> getTransactions() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("call transactions");
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
        Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3j.web3ClientVersion().send();
        String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
        System.out.println("clientVersion......." + clientVersion);
        BigInteger block = web3j.ethBlockNumber().send().getBlockNumber();
        System.out.println("blockno:" + block.intValue());
        Flowable<Transaction> transactions =  web3j.replayPastTransactionsFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST,
                DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).serialize();
        return  transactions;
    }
}
```

Comment: as i said you can't get the transactions of a very big range of blocks, it will just crash. 
you should set limits. You can do it like this instead of DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST to DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(BigInteger.valueOf(30)); or 300 ....

Comment: Thanks alot., will research more on this.,i would like to connect with u over Linkdin,here's an link to connect with me: https://www.linkedin.com/in/aniket-tikone-27808a138

Comment: Getting error on your code snippet :No converter found for return value of type: class io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSerialized

Comment: This serialized come from your old code from the last question before u edit it

Comment: That code worked for me with the last webj version and Java 11

Comment: I would like to connect with u over Linkdin for future opportunities,here's an link to connect with me: https://www.linkedin.com/in/aniket-tikone-27808a138

Comment: @antiket okay will do later, but I would rather help, answer and respond for questions hier